# Page navigation after selecting/saving data to page different than what started with

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I currently have a page which displays two buttons both when clicked go to different pages and i wanted when the user is done with completing whatever they are doing and save i wanted them routed back to the page they started from (the page displaying the two buttons).

The path where the page with buttons is: .../School/CreatePartySchool...

Fieldset on page that is displayed with the two buttons:

```
<fieldset>
<legend>Schools</legend>
<div id="address">
    <%Html.RenderPartial("SchoolAddress"); %>
</div>
<div id="buttonSaveCancelAlign" style="margin-bottom: 4px">
    <a class="glossyBtn" href='<%:Url.Action("Create", "School")%>'>
                <img style="vertical-align: middle" alt="" src="<%:Url.Content("~/Content/blueprint/plugins/buttons/icons/add.png")%>" />
                <span style="vertical-align: middle">Add School</span> </a>

    <input class="glossyBtn" type="submit" name="button" style="vertical-align: middle; padding-right: 13px;" value="Select School"/>
```

After clicking the Select School .... selecting and saving school

The page returned to is: .../Party/Edit (this page is a level higher than /Schools/CreatePartySchool. I want it to return to /Schools/CreatePartySchool).

Answer (score 0):

your questions do not define the problem..wht u actlly trying to do.as per my knowledge navigation can be handled from code behind,in the onclick event for the button.